# Options for moving large amount of documents to library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-database

I am working on **migrating** documents from our **RDBM**S (Oracle) to a given SharePoint 2013 library (1 site collection, 1 content database). The total size of the documents to be migrated is over **400GB** which exceeds the limit recommended by MS. The collection in its current state has some workflows. I am not an SP expert but curious to hear from the experts here before proposing something.

Are there any workarounds to making this happen in a way that is seamless to the users/applications? We also have .NET applications reading and writing to this library. Here are some ideas i have in mind:

1. Split the content database in such a way that users/applications still hit the same site collection from a front-end/search perspective but in the backend, the content database is split up. I am not sure if this is possible.
2. Create additional site collections with their own content databases (essentially split the primary site collection) and have the primary site collection read and write to libraries in the newly created collections in a fashion that doesn't impact the users/applications. The primary site collection can route the document to the appropriate library and users performing search on primary site collection will still get results from all the site collections. Again, I am not sure if this is possible

Splitting the site collection such that main site collection is no longer the primary/entry point is not a preferred option. Please help